# Express Ignores RegExp routes, but serves string routes?

Tags: node.js, express, zappa

I'm met with a perplexing issue today. I've been building a CMS system in Zappa, which uses the Express framework. I'm doing custom routing, so I have quite a few "Catch all" routes. Basically, if a route isn't claimed by the system, this instead pings the database and sees if the user has defined content at that route, and displays it if it exists.

This was working beautifully until today. I don't know what I did (I was working on something completely different and made about a bazillion changes) but suddenly RegExp routes stopped working. Completely, it's as though Express just ignores them alltogether.

The following code works:

```
get '/', ->
    render 'some_view'
```

and the following code does not:

```
get /\//, ->
    render 'some_view'
```

This is just an example of course. *All* RegExp routes are being ignored.

I'm at a loss. I've tried removing the dynamicHelpers that I was working, on, my entire auth module (which didn't exist before today) and every other major thing I could think of in turn. I haven't done anything to node.js other than install bcrypt and node-validator. Why is Express suddenly ignoring one type of route, but not another?

Comment: As a a sanity check, do some routes with a longer path like `/foo/` and `foo` and make sure those work.  Maybe the root route of just a slash has some special case implications.

Comment: Tried all of that. /foo/, /\/foo/, and even /.*/ all fail.

Comment: This is a tough one, from your explanation it seems like it might be a strange dependency issue stemming from some of the seemingly unrelated changes or new modules.  You should try to step back through your git repository until it works and then find exactly where it fails.  Otherwise you might want to hop on the #node.js IRC channel on freenode.net -- you may even catch one of the core node or the express architect on there, at any rate somebody who knows more about the internals should have a quick idea of where the conflict is.

Comment: Have you tried making a dummy app that serves simple text/whatever using RegExp routes? Something like `require('zappa') -> @get /\//, 'hi'`. Are you *using* Zappa's shorthand `@get`?

Comment: I had tried a dummy app, yes, and got the same results. I wiped node, reinstalled, migrated to Zappa 3.0 in the process, and the problem disappeared. As such, I guess this problem is now invalid? I'm voting to close it.